# Facebook api key hash

Tags: android, facebook

Why we use Key hash when developing Facebook Api (Login with facebook) in android ? 
I need a lot of information about it and I have problem to get the key hash

1. from Android code I can't find key hash in logcat.
2. from CMD I get the key hash constant at every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in onCreate.
Code to get key hash from Facebook

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

Comment: i use this code but how i find the key hash after this ?

Comment: Pls Check your logcat,you get KeyHash in your log with TAG->KeyHash

Comment: can you send to me an image for this to my email 
i.mahmoud.gamal@gmail.com
thanks in advanced